# SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:841)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

I am attempting to connect to Neo4j but I keep getting this error. I tried

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "12345"))
```

but I get this error when I try to connect

SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:841)'

I can connect to the browser when I type http://localhost:7474/browser/

Here is the full error log:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- SSLEOFError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   _secure(s, host, ssl_context, **config)
>       853         try:
>   --> 854             s = ssl_context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host if HAS_SNI and host else None)
>       855         except SSLError as cause:
>
> c:\program files\python36\lib\ssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock,
>   server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs,
>   server_hostname, session)
>       406                          server_hostname=server_hostname,
>   --> 407                          _context=self, _session=session)
>       408
>
> c:\program files\python36\lib\ssl.py in **init**(self, sock, keyfile,
>   certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs,
>   do_handshake_on_connect, family, type, proto, fileno,
>   suppress_ragged_eofs, npn_protocols, ciphers, server_hostname,
>   _context, _session)
>       813                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for
>   non-blocking sockets")
>   --> 814                     self.do_handshake()
>       815
>
> c:\program files\python36\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self, block)
>   1067                 self.settimeout(None)
>   -> 1068             self._sslobj.do_handshake()    1069         finally:
>
> c:\program files\python36\lib\ssl.py in do_handshake(self)
>       688         """Start the SSL/TLS handshake."""
>   --> 689         self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>       690         if self.context.check_hostname:
>
> SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:841)
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> SecurityError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 
>   ----> 2 driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "12345"))
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neo4j__init__.py in
>   driver(cls, uri, **config)
>       118         :class:`.Driver` subclass instance directly.
>       119         """
>   --> 120         return Driver(uri, **config)
>       121 
>       122
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neo4j__init__.py in
>   **new**(cls, uri, **config)
>       159         for subclass in Driver.**subclasses**():
>       160             if parsed_scheme in subclass.uri_schemes:
>   --> 161                 return subclass(uri, **config)
>       162         raise ValueError("URI scheme %r not supported" % parsed.scheme)
>       163
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neo4j__init__.py in
>   **new**(cls, uri, **config)
>       233 
>       234         pool = ConnectionPool(connector, instance.address, **config)
>   --> 235         pool.release(pool.acquire())
>       236         instance._pool = pool
>       237         instance._max_retry_time = config.get("max_retry_time", default_config["max_retry_time"])
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   acquire(self, access_mode)
>       713 
>       714     def acquire(self, access_mode=None):
>   --> 715         return self.acquire_direct(self.address)
>       716 
>       717
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   acquire_direct(self, address)
>       606                 if can_create_new_connection:
>       607                     try:
>   --> 608                         connection = self.connector(address, error_handler=self.connection_error_handler)
>       609                     except ServiceUnavailable:
>       610                         self.remove(address)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neo4j__init__.py in
>   connector(address, **kwargs)
>       230 
>       231         def connector(address, **kwargs):
>   --> 232             return connect(address, **dict(config, **kwargs))
>       233 
>       234         pool = ConnectionPool(connector, instance.address, **config)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   connect(address, **config)
>       970         raise ServiceUnavailable("Failed to resolve addresses for %s" % address)
>       971     else:
>   --> 972         raise last_error
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   connect(address, **config)
>       961             host = address[0]
>       962             s = _connect(resolved_address, **config)
>   --> 963             s, der_encoded_server_certificate = _secure(s, host, security_plan.ssl_context, **config)
>       964             connection = _handshake(s, address, der_encoded_server_certificate, **config)
>       965         except Exception as error:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\neobolt\direct.py in
>   _secure(s, host, ssl_context, **config)
>       857             error = SecurityError("Failed to establish secure connection to {!r}".format(cause.args[1]))
>       858             error.**cause** = cause
>   --> 859             raise error
>       860         else:
>       861             # Check that the server provides a certificate
>
> SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to 'EOF occurred
>   in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:841)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem with the Object Graph Mapper Neomodel (connecting to neo4j v4). Adding the second line solved it:

```
config.DATABASE_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:password123@localhost:7687'
config.ENCRYPTED_CONNECTION = False
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution for people who might have the same issue.  You need to add `encrypted=False`.

Instead of

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "12345"))
```

it should be:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "12345"), encrypted=False)
```

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, answer from Sam did not resolve it, however. Using

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver( encrypted=False, uri, auth=('neo4j', 'asdf'))
```

I get the error `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

typing the `uri`directly into the command like this: `driver = GraphDatabase.driver( encrypted=False, uri = "bolt://localhost:7687", auth=('neo4j', 'asdf'))` resulted in another error (`SecurityError: Failed to establish secure connection to '[SSL: KRB5_S_TKT_NYV] unexpected eof while reading (_ssl.c:1076)'`)

When following a [post in the neo4j community](https://community.neo4j.com/t/certificate-issue-with-python-driver-for-neoj4-v4-0/15158) however, they switch positions of the arguments to this:

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, auth=('neo4j', 'asdf')encrypted=False)
```

it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me, **encrypted** as additional param.

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver( uri, auth=('neo4j', 'asdf'), encrypted=False)
```